# Loop trough array and sum the length

Tags: javascript

EDITED:

Can someone help me with the problem below further. I have a class and an array inside the class. I want now use a for loop to sum the length of the previous array length, but for each iteration. If i == 1 I want sum the length of arr[0].x.length, If i == 2 I want sum the length of arr[0].x.length+arr[1].x.length, ect. It will be a lot of code to check each iteration.

Is there a simple way to do this? Instead allways use a new line like

```
if (i == 1) n = n + arr[i-1].x.length;
if (i == 2) n = n + arr[i-1].x.length+arr[i-2].x.length;
if (i == 3) n = n + arr[i-1].x.length+arr[i-2].x.length+arr[i-3].x.length;

function Class() {
 var x = [];
}

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  arr[i] = new Class();
}

I add 4 items to each object.
arr[0].x.push(...)
arr[0].x.push(...)
...
arr[1].x.push(...)
arr[1].x.push(...)
...

var n = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (i == 1) {
    n = n + arr[i-1].x.length;
  } else if (i == 2) {
    n = n + arr[i-1].x.length+arr[i-2].x.length;
  } else if (i == 3) {
    n = n + arr[i-1].x.length+arr[i-2].x.length+arr[i-3].x.length;
  }
  // ect.
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the output you expect for a given array? Can you [edit] your answer and add a [mcve]?

Comment: What does your `arr1` array look like? Is it a 2D array?

Comment: Sounds like your looking for [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `reduce` to get a total of all the lengths of your sub-arrays. For example:

```js
const arrs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
const sum = arrs.reduce((acc, arr) => acc += arr.length, 0);
console.log(sum);
// 6
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybee my question is not clear enough or missunderstood. I edit my question above. I try to sum the previous length for each interation. So if i == 1 sum the length of arr[0].x.length, if i == 2 sum the the length of arr[0].x.length + arr[1].x.length, ect

Comment: @JCss - not sure I am understanding. Maybe it would help if you edited your question with an example of the starting array i.e.`[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` and an example of the expected output: is it a single number, an array of numbers, something else?

Comment: I have a class and in this class there is a integer array "x". I create for example 4 instances of the class which is an array (named as arr) and add to each object(x array) numbers. Now I want go trough the class array(arr) and the x array and count the length of the x array from the previous class array . If **i == 1** count the sum of arr(i-1).x.length, If **i == 2** count the sum of arr(i-1).x.length+arr(i-2).x.length

Comment: @JCss - I read your question edit which I think explains the same process as your comment, and I think you are trying to create an array of arrays and then sum the lengths of all the arrays that come before a specific index in the parent array. But, I am still not sure what you want the output to look like. Instead of explaining the process, it would be better if you could post an example of your array of arrays along with an example of what the output should look like (I think that would clear it up for me and others).

Comment: The output should match the SVG objects. I need this because I use SVG and add for example 16 objects to the DOM. In the same time I have a class with the array. So when I loop trough the class array and the array inside the class it does not match the SVG objects. Assume there are 4 instances of the class and 4 items in x array, and 16 SVG objects(children.length). When I loop trough the class array and x array, arr(i) will count from 0 to 3 and x(j) from 0 to 3, then arr(i) from 4 to 7 and from 0 to 3, ect. As you see I "can't" match the SVG.children[n]. Therefore I try to sum the length...

Answer (score 1):

Just nest the loop two times: go over the indexes once then go up to that index from 0 in an inner loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
     n = n + arr1[j].length;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: benvc's answer is what you are looking for if you want to use reduce.

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7]];
var n = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 n += arr[i].length;
}

console.log(n);
```